# Page keeps loading for a very long time even after an explicit wait (Selenium Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Currently, I am exploring the web with `selenium`. Specifically, I am using `selenium` to visit website X for each request. After navigating to website X, the WebDriver is supposed to wait for the presence of a certain element (maximum of 5 seconds). However, it is very odd to me that, once in a while, the WebDriver is loading website X for a very long time. Usually 20-45 seconds. How is it possible this happens when I have implemented an explicit wait after each request? Here is the code:

```
   for i in range(1000):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get('https://www.canva.com/login')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.sMwixw')))
        driver.close()
```

Can anyone explain this behavior? If so, how can I avoid it? That is, to not wait longer than 5 seconds for each request as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to set pageload strategy to none:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, desired_capabilities={"page_load_strategy": "none"})
```

Otherwise it will wait until it thinks the page loaded, then 5 more seconds for the selector